# REACT Cannot read property 'value' of null at onKeyPress

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component called EmailSubscribe that takes the value of a text input box and sends it through a fetch request. I have saved two elements into variables, emailInput and emailContainer, however, I am getting the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at onKeyPress
```

I have not had this issue with other components and my code works if I replace emailInput and emailContainer with document.querySelector('XXXX') each time I need it, but this is not a clean way of doing it. Any idea why I'm getting this error message?

**App.js**:

```
import ResultsPage from "./pages/ResultsPage/results";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import EmailSubscribe from "./components/EmailSubscribe";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <ResultsPage />
      <EmailSubscribe />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**EmailSubscribe.jsx**:

```
function EmailSubscribe() {
  const emailContainer = document.querySelector(".email-container");
  const emailInput = document.querySelector(".email-input");

  const isValidEmail = (email) => {
    var validEmailRegex = /\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/;
    return validEmailRegex.test(email);
  };

  const resetEmailSubscribe = (newValue, newPlaceholder, isErrorMessage) => {
    emailInput.value = newValue;
    emailInput.placeholder = newPlaceholder;
    if (isErrorMessage) {
      emailInput.classList.add("placeholderColorOrange");
    } else {
      emailInput.classList.remove("placeholderColorOrange");
    }
  };

  const emailSubscribePOST = (email) => {
    if (email.trim() == "") {
      resetEmailSubscribe("", "Please enter your email address", true);
    } else if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
      resetEmailSubscribe("", "Invalid email address", true);
    } else {
      fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/subscribe", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email: email }),
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.message == "Email sent successfully") {
            emailContainer.innerHTML =
              "<p class='email-thankyou'>Thank you for subscribing!</p>";
          } else if (res.message == "Email already registered") {
            resetEmailSubscribe("", res.message, true);
          }
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div class="email-container">
      <input
        type="text"
        className="email-input"
        placeholder="Register or log in"
        onKeyPress={(e) =>
          e.key === "Enter" && emailSubscribePOST(emailInput.value)
        }
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        className="email-submit-btn btn"
        onClick={() => {
          emailSubscribePOST(emailInput.value);
        }}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default EmailSubscribe;
```

Comment: At the time when document.querySelector(".email-input") is called, the component is not mounted - or even rendered - yet, so it will return null. Note the whole philosophy of React is to not reach out directly to the DOM, but instead to use the api they provide - ie the react hooks - to manage the state of your application in a way that integrates with the react lifecycle. In this way, react takes care of everything relating to the DOM and you don't really have to worry too much about when it is actually ready to be accessed.

Comment: thanks for your input, this is great context!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, don't access items with document.get... in react. In React you have state for the things you are doing.

```
function EmailSubscribe() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = useState("Register or log in");
  const [hasSubscribed, setHasSubscribed] = useState(false);
  const [hasErrorMessage, setHasErrorMessage] = useState(false);

  const isValidEmail = (email) => {
    var validEmailRegex = /\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/;
    return validEmailRegex.test(email);
  };

  const resetEmailSubscribe = (newValue, newPlaceholder, hasErrorMessage) => {
    setInput(newValue);
    setPlaceholder(newPlaceholder);
    setHasErrorMessage(hasErrorMessage);
  };

  const emailSubscribePOST = (email) => {
    if (email.trim() == "") {
      resetEmailSubscribe("", "Please enter your email address", true);
    } else if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
      resetEmailSubscribe("", "Invalid email address", true);
    } else {
      fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/subscribe", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email: email }),
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.message == "Email sent successfully") {
            setHasSubscribed(true)
          } else if (res.message == "Email already registered") {
            resetEmailSubscribe("", res.message, true);
          }
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div class="email-container">
      {hasSubscribed ? 
        <p class='email-thankyou'>Thank you for subscribing!</p>
        :
        <input
          type="text"
          className={hasErrorMessage ? "placeholderColorOrange" : ""}
          placeholder={emailInputPlaceholder}
          onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)}
          value={input}
          onKeyPress={(e) =>
            e.key === "Enter" && emailSubscribePOST(input)
          }
        />
        <button
          type="button"
          className="email-submit-btn btn"
          onClick={() => {
            emailSubscribePOST(input);
          }}
        >
        Submit
        </button>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default EmailSubscribe;
```

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you! However, I'm now unable to type in the input box? I'm not too sure how to update the input state from the input box

Comment: I added onChange={(e) => setEmailInputValue(e.target.value)} and it worked great, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot that, I am gonna edit it.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is you do not have a value attribute in your input text box.Try adding the 'value' attribute to your input text and set the state with onChange like below:

```
<input
        type="text"
        className="email-input"
        placeholder="Register or log in"
        value={emailInput}
        onChange={(e)=>setEmailInput(e.value)
        onKeyPress={(e) =>
          e.key === "Enter" && emailSubscribePOST(emailInput)
        }
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        className="email-submit-btn btn"
        onClick={() => {
          emailSubscribePOST(emailInput);
        }}
      >
```

It should work.

Comment: This was really helpful thanks, I actually used onChange={(e) => setEmailInputValue(e.target.value)} and that worked!